# Ideal way to handle layout changes in a list

Tags: expressionengine

So I've stupidly designed a list of recent articles, all is good with the world BUT the first 2 entries html are markedly different then the remainder of entries.

I am yet to turn a line of code so any advice anyone an offer is greatly appreciated.

Simplistically the ul would look like:

```
<li class="1of2"> /* It's number 1 – give it a class to identify it as special */
<h1>{title}</h1>
<p>{short_desc}</p>
</li>
<li class="1of2"> /* It's number 2 – give it a class to identify it as special */
<h1>{title}</h1>
<p>{short_desc}</p>
</li>
<li> /* It's not number 1 or 2 – ie. every other item, NO class per se */
<h1>{title}</h1>
<p>{short_desc}</p>
</li>
```

If you imagine a 3 column grid for all entries but the first 2 entries are 1.5 columns each. Bit of a noodle scratch going on here, any thoughts gratefully voted upon.

**PS. I will be using Stash if that helps !**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just output the class name based on the value of `{count}`. I've output the whole opening `<li>` tag here to keep it simple but you could just output the class attribute or class name itself.

```
{if count<=2}
    <li class="special">
{if:else}
    <li>
{/if}
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        ... etc.
    </li>
```

Incidentally, I don't think you can have class names that begin with a number.

Comment: Thanks all, they're all invaluable inputs but I had to select one answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it if you want each of the first 2 to have a unique class name:

```
<li{if count<=2}class="top{count}"{/if}>
```

that will output

```
<li class="top1">...
<li class="top2">...
<li>...
```

If you want the first 2 items to have the same class:

```
<li{if count<=2}class="whateveryouwant"{/if}>
```

which will output

```
<li class="whateveryouwant">...
<li class="whateveryouwant">...
<li>...
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do `{if count == "1|2"}class="whatever"{/if}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are asking for two unique classes, one for the first entry and one for the second entry. In that case, this will work:

```
{if count == 1}
    <li class="first">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{short_desc}</p>
    </li>
{if:else if count == "2"}
    <li class="second">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{short_desc}</p>
    </li>
{if:else}
    <li>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{short_desc}</p>
    </li>
{/if}
```

Also, class names that start with a number will not validate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with simple conditionals as well if there is no "other" class that would then require the if:else part of the conditional:

```
<li{if count == "1"} class="first"{/if}{if count == "2"} class="second"{/if}">
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{short_desc}</p>
</li>
```

This assumes you don't have any other differences, such as different custom fields in one option versus the other, which MediaGirl's suggestion would handle more elegantly.  If the only difference between them is class assignment, this is another alternative.